# Converting a Recursive program to loop based only

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, recursion, tail-recursion

How can I modify the code (**without using recursive calls**) so that it only adds to the queue as long as the queue size is not more than 100,000 items.
Otherwise it waits for 5 seconds for queue items to be processed, (items are to be removed from the queue once they are processed) and then starts adding items again if there is space in the queue. Otherwise waits another 5 secs (and so on). The parts in comments "#" is the functionality I'm suggesting. I dont mind a recursive solution as long as its a recursive Tail Call Optimisation method so I dont encounter the recursive depth limit issue.

```
url_input_file = array of strings
def worker():
                while threading.active_count() > 0:
                                url = q.get()
                                sendRequest(url)
                                q.task_done()

q = Queue()

for threads in range(1000):
                t = threading.Thread(target = worker)
                t.daemon = True
                t.start()

for url in url_input_file:
            #if len(q) < 100000:
                q.put(url)
            #else:
                #time.sleep(5)
                #try to send it in the queue again

q.join()
```

Comment: Why don't you just make a bounded queue, so `put` blocks until the workers get enough work done?

Comment: What version of Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by inverting the queue size check and sleeping until queue space is freed up, something like

```
for url in url_input_file:
    while len(q) >= 100000:
        time.sleep(5)
    q.put(url)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Will try it!